# Rails: handle incomplete procedures due to back button or

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rollback

I'm using Rails 6. Suppose there is an online shop with some `items` to sell. Clicking on the `payment` button, takes the client to the payment gateway and takes some minutes and steps to be done.

How we can prevent double payment? what are the best practice?

I have added an attribute 'status' which is 'available' by default. Clicking on the `payment` button, changes it to prevent double payment. Now, what's the best way or best practices to handle incomplete payments when user clicks on back button, or close the browser or ... ? How to make these `items` available again?

I know the question is general, but I hope you can help me understand the best practices and different approaches available.

Comment: If you want to guarantee that an item will be reserved when a user adds them to the cart you need to create the record as soon as they add the first item. This would then create a lock against the item inventory. You then need to create a job which will execute after x number of minutes to purge the order if its not completed.

Comment: @max thanks for your comment. yes, I was thinking of using clock but I was not sure how efficient it is. I'll try that.